# Using JOIN to include NULL values

Tags: php, mysql

My goal to combine results from two tables (predictions and user_score) so that I have all users who scored the points in the match and who did not score the points, but are participating in the pool (poolid=110)

**predictions**

```
predid    | matchid  | ueserid    | points |
--------------------------------------------
1            121            8        1
2            122            8        2
3            122            10       3
```

**user_score**

```
id    | poolid  | userid    | 
------------------------------
1         110            8
2         110            10
3         111            8
4         111            10
```

**Results should be like that:**

```
| matchid  | ueserid    | points |  poolid 
--------------------------------------------
  121            8          1      110
  null           10         null   110
```

This is few queries that i tried:

```
SELECT * FROM predictions LEFT JOIN user_score on predictions.userid = user_score.userid WHERE predictions.matchid=121 and user_score.poolid=110

SELECT * FROM predictions RIGHT JOIN user_score on predictions.userid = user_score.userid WHERE predictions.matchid=121 and user_score.poolid=110
```

This query doesnt work on my SQL version Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.31 / Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 /

```
SELECT * FROM predictions FULL OUTER JOIN user_score on predictions.userid = user_score.userid WHERE predictions.matchid=121 and user_score.poolid=110
```

I need help :)

Comment: MySQL does not support FULL OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN, and put the condition `matchid = 121` into the ON clause:

```
select p.matchid, s.userid, p.points, s.poolid 
from user_score s
left join predictions p
  on  p.userid  = s.userid
  and p.matchid = 121
where s.poolid = 110
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a1a5/1

You can also use your RIGHT JOIN method, but the `matchid = 121` condition must be in the ON clause.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a1a5/6